# spyOn not able to spy on the method of a dependent service

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I am testing `AuthService` which sends user login info to server using another `HelperService`.

```
public authServiceSigninUser(user:UserSigninInfo):any{
    console.log('In authServiceSigninUser. contacting server at '+this.API_URL +this.SIGNIN_USER_URL +" with user data "+user+ " with httpOptions "+httpOptions.withCredentials + ","+httpOptions.headers ); //TODOM password should be sent in encrypted format.

    let signinInfo= new UserSigninAPI(user);
    let body = JSON.stringify(signinInfo);
    return this.helperService.sendMessage(this.SIGNIN_USER_URL,body,httpOptions)
  }
```

I am trying to test the `authServiceSigninUser` method as follows but when I run the spec, I get error `Error: <spyOn> : sendMessage() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)`. Why?

```
describe('authServiceSigninUser test suite',()=>{
  beforeEach(()=>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AuthService, HelperService]
    });
  });
  fit('should sign in user',()=>{
    let spy:any;
    let helper = TestBed.get(HelperService);
    let authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    let userSignIn = new UserSigninInfo("test@test.com","test");
    let httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    spyOn(helper.sendMessage,'sendMessage');
    let observable:Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = authService.authServiceSigninUser(userSignIn);
    let subscription = observable.subscribe((event)=>{
      console.log('event from authService',event);
    });
    const responseData = { result: 'success', ['additional-info']: 'login success' };
    let httpEvent:HttpResponse<any> = new HttpResponse<any>({body:responseData});
    expect(helper.sendMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();//ERROR here
    const mockReq:TestRequest = httpMock.expectOne(environment.apiUrl+environment.signinUserUrl); //Expect that a single request has been made which matches the given URL, and return its mock
    //once mocking of sending request is done, mock receiving a response. This will trigger the logic inside subscribe function
    mockReq.flush(httpEvent); //flush method provides dummy values as response
    httpMock.verify();//verify checks that there are no outstanding requests;

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the correct way is `spyOn(helper,'sendMessage');`, not `spyOn(helper.sendMessage,'sendMessage');`

Comment: The answer is already in the question: ``Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)``